# How can I run Selenium Webdiver test cases(Maven Project) in virtual server space through Jenkins with Headless browser?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, maven-2, jenkins-plugins, xvfb

I have one project which is based on maven.It is run correctly in local machine with `mvn clean install exec:java` command.

This is my `Pom.xml` to run maven project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>AutomationMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>AutomationMaven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AutomationMaven</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.43.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.43.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                     <configuration>
                             <source>1.7</source>
                             <target>1.7</target>
                             <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                             <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                             <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                             <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                             <fork>true</fork>
                     </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>  
                       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
                       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                       <version>1.2.1</version>  
                       <configuration>  
                          <mainClass>com.mainClass</mainClass>  
                       </configuration>  
                 </plugin>  
         </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have already set up "GIT repository" for it which is align with "Jenkins Job".

I have made on job in "Jenkins" with this parameter
- JDK 7
- Xvfb setup(Need More Info about configuration)
- maven command = mvn clean install exec:java

I have different server for Run Maven Project (Selenium Test).

I have getting following Track trace (Error) while run project on Server :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"mcHeaderLink"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.03 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
System info: host: 'ip-10-120-0-202', ip: '10.120.0.202', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-58-virtual', java.version: '1.7.0_72'
Session ID: 6c37455f-1dbe-4a8f-acd4-a2b21ae6ec00
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=26.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:393)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:37)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.click(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way that can help you.

But you require a dedicated server space and a display for running your selenium script. Display is required for javascript operations.

You have to configure jenkins job with your repository first.

Once you get repository you have to run that project with the help of mvn exec:java.

Please confirm your JRE version in jenkins with maven-compiler-plugin. It should be same.

Once you are able to successfully run the jenkins job, you can check it in your jenkins console log.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say why it does not work, as you said nothing about your application. But "NoSuchElementException" suggests that the tests are running and just cannot find the required element.

Take a look at your application logfile and check if it is really running.

You may dump a screenshot to see your application state in case of error.
see [Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)